# How to insert non-string value in jsonlite::toJSON()

Tags: r, json

I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
head(iris[c(1,5)], n = 3) %>%   
 mutate(qtc = "{smooth: 7}")  %>% 
 jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
```

Which create this output:

```
[
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 5.1,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": "{smooth: 7}"
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.9,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": "{smooth: 7}"
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.7,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": "{smooth: 7}"
  }
]
```

Notice that for this entry `"qtc": "{smooth: 7}"` the value  `"{smooth: 7}"` is under quote.
How can I remove that quote in my code. 
The desired result is:

```
[
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 5.1,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {"smooth": 7}
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.9,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {"smooth": 7}
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.7,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {"smooth": 7}
  }
]
```

Comment: Why do you need that? What is the actual use-case?

Comment: @RonakShah I am trying to submit JSON for genome track view in WashU Browser.
https://epigenomegateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datahub.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
head(iris[c(1,5)], n = 3) %>%   
  mutate(qtc = list(list(smooth = 7)))  %>% 
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)

[
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 5.1,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {
      "smooth": 7
    }
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.9,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {
      "smooth": 7
    }
  },
  {
    "Sepal.Length": 4.7,
    "Species": "setosa",
    "qtc": {
      "smooth": 7
    }
  }
]
```